# Resource route call to wrong method in Vue component

Tags: php, laravel, vue-component

I have created route with "resource". When I try to use delete method it always going to show method.

-Route Calll(in Vue component)

```
<a class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-100 text green-800"v-bind:href="'translate-breed/' + breedDetail.id">Delete
</a>
```

- Route List

[image]

-Delete Method

```
public function destroy(TranslateBreed $translateBreed)
    {
        $translateBreed->delete();
        session()->flash('flash_message', 'The Breed has been deleted.');
        return redirect()->route('translate-breed.index');
    }
```

When I working with php blade file this issue has occurred & in that case I have handdle it as follows,

```
<form method="POST" class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-100 text-green-800" action="{{ route('translate-breed.destroy',['translate_breed' => $breed->id]) }}">
 @csrf
 @method("delete")
<button class="px-2 inline-flex text-xs leading-5 font-semibold rounded-full bg-red-100 text-green-800">
Delete
</button>
</form>
```

How to overcome this issue.

Thank You!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use some library like Axios in your Vue component that allows you to set the method on each request. Create a method in your component that makes use of it.

1. Call a method from your link:

```
<a href="" @click.prevent="deleteTranslate(breedDetail.id)">Delete</a>
```

2. Create the method from where to make the call with Axios:

```
 deleteTranslate(id) {
            axios
                .delete("translate-breed/" + id)
                .then(response => {
                //Do something
                });
        },
```

Don't forget to include axios dependency in your project.